# Fix TypeError: Cannot read property 'onNewRows' of undefined in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

In ag-grid I have the response and I want to arrange them into my grid but I'm getting an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'onNewRows' of undefined` I think this error is from  grid API as it is not Initialising.failure image are attached below find them.[image: $scope.userReqPages.api is missing]

Answer (score 0):

Fields api undefined means that the grid did not initialized yet.

Either wait for ready event before performing your request or/and check if your binding ag-grid="userReqPages" is correct.

By the way use api.setRowData() when you want to refresh datas.